# Как получить актуальные данные за пределами метода onSuccess

Tags: android, rxjava

Есть фрагмент `Fragment1`. Логика его работы такова: Из активити передаем данные (id, songTitle, songImage, songFile и т.д.) во фрагмент и проигрывается музыка.

Во фрагменте есть кнопки `Next` и `Prev`. Нажав на любую из них вызывается метод `selectData()`, куда передаем `id` следующей или предыдущей песни. В методе `selectData()` используя `RxJava` идет выбор из БД нужной песни по его `ID`. В методе `onSuccess` всегда получаю информацию о нужной (следующей или предыдущей) песне и записываю данные о песне в переменные `id, songTitle, songImage, songFile`. И эти данные используются в методе `startPlayerService`, который начинает воспроизведение.

Но проблема в том, что когда нажимаю `Next` или `Prev` в методе `onSuccess` получаю инфо о нужной песне, а в метод `startPlayerService` попадает информация о предыдущей песне.

Как это можно исправить/решить?

Надеюсь понятно объяснить.

Fragment 1

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    private RoundedImageView imgFairytales;
    private TextView txtFairytales;
    private TextView txtAuthor;
    private AdView mAdView;
    private ImageButton exo_pause;
    private ImageButton exo_play;
    private ImageButton btnNext;
    private ImageButton btnPrev;

    private int songsCount = 0;

    private int id;
    private int currentID;
    private String songTitle;
    private String songImage;
    private String songFile;
    private String songAuthor;
    private String songText;

    static boolean isPlay = false;

    private OnDataSelectListener onDataSelectListener;

    public static Fragment1 newInstance(int id, String songTitle, String songImage, String songFile, String songAuthor, String songText, int songsCount) {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("id", id);
        args.putString("songTitle", songTitle);
        args.putString("songImage", songImage);
        args.putString("songFile", songFile);
        args.putString("songAuthor", songAuthor);
        args.putString("songText", songText);
        args.putInt("songsCount", songsCount);

        Fragment1 fragment1 = new Fragment1();
        fragment1.setArguments(args);
        return fragment1;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container, false);

        imgFairytales = rootView.findViewById(R.id.imgFairytales);
        txtFairytales = rootView.findViewById(R.id.txtFairytales);
        txtAuthor = rootView.findViewById(R.id.txtAuthor);

        KidsPlayer.playerView = new PlayerView(getContext());
        KidsPlayer.playerView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.player);

        exo_pause = rootView.findViewById(R.id.exo_pause);
        exo_play = rootView.findViewById(R.id.exo_play);
        btnNext = rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnNext);
        btnPrev = rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnPrev);

        mAdView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.adView);

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        id = getArguments().getInt("id", 0);
        songTitle = getArguments().getString("songTitle");
        songImage = getArguments().getString("songImage");
        songFile = getArguments().getString("songFile");
        songAuthor = getArguments().getString("songAuthor");
        songText = getArguments().getString("songText");
        songsCount = getArguments().getInt("songsCount");

        txtFairytales.setText(songTitle);
        txtAuthor.setText(songAuthor);

        Glide.with(getActivity()).load(Uri.parse("file:///android_asset/img/" + songImage + ".jpg")).into(imgFairytales);

        startPlayerService();

        btnPrev.setOnClickListener(this);
        exo_pause.setOnClickListener(this);
        exo_play.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnNext.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.btnPrev:
                onPrev();
                setScaleAnimation(view);
                break;
            case R.id.exo_pause:
                stopPlayerService();
                setScaleAnimation(view);
                break;
            case R.id.exo_play:
                startPlayerService();
                setScaleAnimation(view);
                break;
            case R.id.btnNext:
                onNext();
                setScaleAnimation(view);
                break;
        }
    }

    private void setScaleAnimation(View v) {
        Animation scaleAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.anim.scale);
        v.startAnimation(scaleAnimation);
    }

    private void startPlayerService() {
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), PlayerService.class);
        serviceIntent.putExtra(PlayerService.KEY_STREAM, songFile);
        serviceIntent.putExtra(PlayerService.KEY_TITLE, songTitle);

        System.out.println("songTitle in startPlayerService = " + songTitle);
        System.out.println("songFile in startPlayerService = " + songFile);

        serviceIntent.setAction(PlayerConstants.ACTION.STARTFOREGROUND_ACTION);
        getActivity().startService(serviceIntent);
        isPlay = true;
        if(exo_play.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
            exo_play.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            exo_pause.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }
    }

    private void stopPlayerService() {
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), PlayerService.class);
        serviceIntent.setAction(PlayerConstants.ACTION.STOPFOREGROUND_ACTION);
        getActivity().stopService(serviceIntent);
        isPlay = false;
        if(exo_pause.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
            exo_pause.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            exo_play.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }

    private void onNext() {
        currentID = id + 1;

        if (currentID < 1) {
            btnPrev.setEnabled(false);
        } else {
            btnPrev.setEnabled(true);
            btnNext.setEnabled(true);
            selectData(currentID);
            startPlayerService();
        }
    }

    private void onPrev() {
        currentID = id - 1;

        if (currentID > songsCount) {
            btnNext.setEnabled(false);
        } else {
            btnPrev.setEnabled(true);
            btnNext.setEnabled(true);
            selectData(currentID);
            startPlayerService();
        }
    }

    private void selectData(int idSong) {

        SongDao songDao = AppDatabase.createPersistentDatabase(getActivity()).songDao();

        songDao.getById(idSong).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new DisposableMaybeObserver<Song>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Song song) {

                        id = song.getId();
                        songFile = "file:///android_asset/music/" + song.getFilename() + ".mp3";
                        songTitle = song.getTitle();
                        songImage = song.getImage();
                        songAuthor = song.getAuthor();

                        songText = song.getText();
                        songText = songText.replace("\\n", "\n");

                        txtFairytales.setText(songTitle);
                        txtAuthor.setText(songAuthor);
                        Glide.with(getActivity()).load(Uri.parse("file:///android_asset/img/" + songImage + ".jpg")).into(imgFairytales);

                        onDataSelectListener.onSelectData(songText);

                        currentID = id;

                        System.out.println("id onSuccess = " + id);
                        System.out.println("currentID onSuccess = " + currentID);
                        System.out.println("songTitle onSuccess = " + songTitle);
                        System.out.println("songFile onSuccess = " + songFile);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete() {
                    }
                });


        System.out.println("id exit onSuccess = " + id);
        System.out.println("currentID exit onSuccess = " + currentID);
        System.out.println("songTitle exit onSuccess = " + songTitle);
        System.out.println("songFile exit onSuccess = " + songFile);
    }
}
```

Comment: В приложении нет возможности удалить песню. Бд готовая и ее нельзя менять, только брать данные и ппоигрывать аудио

Comment: Id +1 таким образом я получаю следующую песню. Например если из активити я получил песню с id =2 то при нажатии на next я получаю currentid=2+1 и проигрываю следующую песню. У меня пробоема в том, что в метод startPlayerService не могу получить нужные данные, хотя в onSuccess получаю их

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в том, что вы сразу после старта асинхронного кода в selectData() выполняете startPlayerService(). То есть не дождавшись результата запускаете startPlayerService() со старыми данными. Самый простой вариант решения перенести startPlayerService() в конец onSuccess().